# Can mass increase be measured by current technology?

Tags: thermal-radiation

One Kg of matter heated by 100° C is said to increase its mass by a few nanograms, can that increase be actually measured? Has it ever been verified?

If not, what is the indirect evidence of the mass increase because of hogher temp?

Comment: You know that the temperature is just a measure of average energy of the system, when you have higher temperature, you get more energy, ie, the particles move faster. Special relativity claims that moving can increase the mass.  So we can deduce that hotter  matter has more mass. If you want the proof for this perticular phenomena, I don't know whether some team has done the experiement or not, but I think there are some experiements showing moving increase the mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a recent paper in *Metrologia*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261257435_A_determination_of_Planck%27s_constant_using_the_NRC_watt_balance) which reports a Planck constant measurement using a [Kibble balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt_balance) (known more commonly as a "watt balance") with a relative uncertainty of about $2\times10^{-8}$.
That uncertainty is consistent with the state of the art described in [this description of a much simpler LEGO-based Kibble balance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1699).

Now, if you were to heat a kilogram of water from 0°C to 100°C, you'd have to add [about](https://water.usgs.gov/edu/heat-capacity.html]) 400 kilojoules of thermal energy. As you say, that energy has a relativistic mass equivalent of 
$$
m_\text{equiv} = \frac E{c^2} = \frac{\rm4\times10^5\,J}{\rm9\times10^{16}\,m^2/s^2}
\approx \rm\frac 12\times10^{-11}\,kg
\approx \rm 4\,nanogram
$$
So no: the state of the art for high-precision mass measurements would need to improve its precision by about four orders of magnitude to see the effect you have in mind.